# Numpy - for each element X in array1 find index of first element greater than X in array2

Tags: python, numpy

I have two numpy arrays `x` and `y`

```
x = numpy.array([1,2,3,4,5])
y = numpy.array([1,3,5,7])

z = func(x,y) # z = [2,2,3,3,4]
```

is there a function `func` that will return the above. E.g. the index of the first element in y that is greater than 1 (first element in x) is 2 so z[0]=2

Looking for a one liner vectorized way to do this if it exists. Something that is agnostic to the actual comparison function (less than, greater than, leq, geq, etc)

Comment: If your second array is sorted you can use `np.searchsorted`.

Comment: [numpy.where()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)

Answer (score -1):

1. Create array1 with 15 even numbers.
2. Create array2 with 15 odd numbers.
3. Exchange array1, array2.
4. Addition array1, array2 and put the result in array3.
5. Print all prime number where there are array3.
6. Apply AND, OR, XOR operations using first element in array1 with first element in array2.